# Save Specific Attachment File Types

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code to automatically download (save) received mail attached files.

I need to make a condition to only download (save) `.xlsx` or `.jpg` files.

```
 Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
 Dim sSaveFolder As String
 sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"
 For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
     oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Answer updated, let me know if it works

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

[Simply use Select Case Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

```
Dim FileType As String

For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    FileType = LCase$(Right$(oAttachment.FileName, 4)) ' Last 4 
          Select Case FileType
           Case "xlsx", ".jpg"
          oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName 
        End Select
    Next
```